# Some information about how to correctly extract DateTime from an XML document in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datetime, xpath

I have the following situation.

In a C# program I initialize some object fields using the content of an XML file.

In the XML file I have the 2 followings date time fielnds:

```
<x:Published>May 21 2014</x:Published>
<x:LastUpdated>2014-05-21T17:00:38</x:LastUpdated>
```

As you can see these fields have different format.

To initialize the related object field in my code I found:

```
currentDeepSightVuln.Published = n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:Published", nsmgr) == null ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.ParseExact(n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:Published", nsmgr).InnerText, "MMM dd yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

currentDeepSightVuln.LastUpdated = n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:LastUpdated", nsmgr) == null ? DateTime.MinValue : XmlConvert.ToDateTime(n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:LastUpdated", nsmgr).InnerText);
```

Is it right? Can I use the **XmlConver.ToDateTime()** method also for the firs XML data field? Why they used the **ParseExact()** and not **XmlConvert.ToDateTime()**

Tnx

Comment: XmlConvert.ToDateTime() with a single argument is apparently obsolete.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shd19e3h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And my nit-picking DRY-fanaticism rebels at the sight of n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:LastUpdated", nsmgr) being repeated, instead of using it once, perhaps creating a tiny method that would still allow the main code to remain a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use `XmlConvert.ToDateTime` by specifying the format string, as you're doing with `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
XmlConvert.ToDateTime("May 21 2014", "MMM dd yyyy")
```

This method will end up calling `DateTime.ParseExact`, so it doesn't really matter which option you choose, as long as you're consistent.

For reference, here's the implementation of `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string, string[])`:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(string s, string[] formats)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, (IFormatProvider) DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);
}
```

Comment: ok but what is the exact difference in the use of XmlConvert.ToDateTime() and DateTime.ParseExact() ?

Comment: Nothing. `XmlConvert.ToDateTime()` simply calls `DateTime.ParseExact()` with a specific formatprovider, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The [XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) defines the representation expected for dates and times stored in an XML document. The `XmlConvert.ToDateTime` overloads which only take a single string are expecting to use this format. By using that method, rather than a variant of `DateTime.Parse`, you're saying you expect the interoperable format.

`XmlConvert.ToDateTime` does have overloads which take one or more format parameters to try, but those overloads are still a subset of the full string.

The `Published` date in your file does not conform to the XML Schema `date` data type, so it must be parsed with a method that can handle that format. `DateTime.Parse` can, `XmlConvert.ToDateTime` will reject it as an invalid format.